# ProgrammingError "forum_userprofile" does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Getting this error message using http://lightbird.net/dbe2/forum.html
But I'm not sure how to decipher the error message or where to debug this.
I try to add it in admin and in the actual site.

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/forum/userprofile/add/

relation "forum_userprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "forum_userprofile" WHERE "forum_user...
                           ^

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/forum/userprofile/add/
Django Version:     1.8.2
Exception Type:     ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    

relation "forum_userprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "forum_userprofile" WHERE "forum_user...
                           ^

Exception Location:     /home/--/pdenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute, line 64
Python Executable:  /home//pdenv/bin/python
Python Version:     3.4.3
Python Path:    

['/home/--/dogs-like-me',
'/home/--/pdenv/lib/python34.zip',
'/home/--/pdenv/lib/python3.4',
'/home/--/pdenv/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
'/home/--/pdenv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.4',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
'/home/--/pdenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
'/home/--/pdenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/newrelic-2.52.0.40']

Server time:    Tue, 7 Jul 2015 19:47:39 +0000
```

**EDIT**
I tried adding a forum_userprofile in the admin page and with the python shell but it's giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/seanna/pdenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 264, in __get__
    self.model._meta.object_name,
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; BasicModel is abstract
```

Comment: The Database table `forum_userprofile` doesn't exists. Make sure the table name is spelled correctly or the tables exists.

Comment: The problem is I don't know why it's looking for that table in the first place but I'll double check. Do you have a suggestion as to where that would be found or what file I need to edit modify that?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have not applied migrations: `$ python manage.py migrate`

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/)

Comment: I did: I think the issue is the BaseModel that my models inherit from. e.g. class Model(BaseModel); where BaseModel = BasicModel which has a meta class where abstract is set to true;